# Promise.all function resolving before promise completion with adding data to arrays

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, promise, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to export an array of data objects for later use, though I can use promises to wait till all data has been added to the array before logging, I noticed when I went to use that data I couldn't because even with Promise.all, the length of the array was still zero as if nothing had changed.

I tried having the console log each time the doc.data() was pushed to the exportArray and I noticed that it logs that after it outputs the array. So for example...

Expected Output

```
doc.data() // For Each doc    
Array[] // Filled with data and length 54
Length: 54
```

Actual Output

```
Array[] // Filled with data and length 54
Length: 0
doc.data() // For Each doc
```

---

```
let exportArray = [];
let promises = [];

db.collection('lists').doc('List 1').collection("members")
    .get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        promises.push(
            new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                exportArray.push(doc.data());
                resolve();
                console.log('before');
            })
        );
    });
});

Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
    console.log(exportArray); // Logs correctly with all data with length 54
    console.log(exportArray.length); // Logs as 0 for some reason


});
```

Ideally this should output the exportArray with it's data AND the length being 54. However it does output the data but the length is output as 0. (and yes I clicked on the data array in console and it shows a length of 54)

Why does the array get populated but I'm unable to use methods on it like exportArray.length correctly?

Comment: I am somewhat puzzled at the fact you seem to be getting familiar with promises, but still happen to make a beginner mistake related to asynchronicity by calling Promise.all() on an array that can only be empty. Would it perhaps be better to go back to reading on Javascript's asynchronous nature before fiddling with promises?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must call `Promise.all` on `promises` *after* it has been filled with promises, which happens asynchronously in a `then` callback. Now you execute it synchronously when none of that has happened yet.

So do:

```
db.collection('lists').doc('List 1').collection("members").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    let promises = querySnapshot.docs.map(function(doc) { //  <-- use docs.map
        return doc.data(); // <-- just return `data()`. No need for a new promise
    });
    // Must be here:
    return Promise.all(promises).then(function (exportArray) { // <--- data arg!
        console.log(exportArray);
        console.log(exportArray.length);
    });
});
```

Notes:

- There is no need for `new Promise` when you have the value to resolve with readily available.
- Instead of `forEach`, get the array from the query snapshot with [.docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs) and the JS built-in `.map()`.
- The fact that you see the array in the console but with a length 0 is the behaviour of the console: it only logs the reference to the array, but then when you expand it in the console, it has in the mean time been populated; so you see the data. But it was not there at the moment of the logging, which is what the `length: 0` is telling you.

#### Simplification

According to the firebase documentation, [`doc.data()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot#methods) returns the data, not a promise, so there is no reason to use `Promise.all`, a simple `map` should suffice:

```
db.collection('lists').doc('List 1').collection("members").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    return querySnapshot.docs.map(function(doc) {
        return doc.data();
    });
}).then(function (exportArray) {
    console.log(exportArray);
    console.log(exportArray.length);
});
```

Comment: Can you link to the documentation on .map? I was trying your first solution and I get `querySnapshot.map is not a function`, same for second solution I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Sorry, it should be `.docs.map`. See [QuerySnapshot#docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs). Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

Since `db.collection('lists').doc('List 1').collection("members").get()` returns immediately with a promise that resolves only after the query completes, your code will go on to execute `Promise.all()` against an empty list and also return immediately because there's nothing to wait on.  Some time after that, your snapshots will be ready and `promises` will be populated.

You should call Promises.all() only after the entire array has been populated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with the `db` you use, but just fixing the antipatterns in your code should solve your problem. I guess that's about what your code should look like.

```
db.collection('lists')
  .doc('List 1')
  .collection("members")
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => querySnapshot.map(doc => doc.data())
  .then(promises => Promise.all(promises))
  .then(exportArray => {
    console.log(exportArray); // Logs correctly with all data with length 54
    console.log(exportArray.length); // Logs as 0 for some reason
  })
```

About the antipattern:

- avoid using `new Promise()` and similar. it's rarely necessary, ususally you already have a Promise chanin you can derive from.
- Promises are wrapping values that you don't have yet. Don't try to "unwrap" these values by doing something along the lines of `somePromise.then(value => { externalVariable = value; })` or in your case it's an Array. 
   
  You now have a variable that will (at some point in the future) contain the value you want, but at the moment is empty/invalid. So now you have to implement your own state management to check when the value has become valid; basically duplicating most of the logic of the Promise ;)